# Computing $\bigtriangledown^2(1/r)$

Tags: calculus

Given that:

$$\vec{r} = x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}$$

and $r$ is the magnitude of $\vec{r}$

Then what is:

$$\bigtriangledown^2(1/r)$$

**EDIT:**
I know that $\bigtriangledown^2F(x)$ is the divergence of the gradient of $F(x)$ thus my attempt to solve the question was to compute the gradient of $1/r$ and then compute the divergence of that, yet my attempt is not yielding the correct answer.

The answer should be 0

Comment: Where are your efforts ?

Comment: This website is not for your homework.

Comment: What is the square root of a vector in this case?

Comment: You should provide more information on what answer you got and how you arrived at it. As written, it would be difficult to provide the most targeted and useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: In Cartesian coordinates

$$\bigtriangledown^2f(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z^2}$$and here$$r=|\vec{r}|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$
$$f=\frac{1}{r}=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=\frac{2x^2-y^2-z^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}},\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}=\frac{2y^2-x^2-z^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}},\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2}=\frac{2z^2-y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}$$
$$\bigtriangledown^2f(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z^2}=0$$

See the following links which verify the results:

[Gradient](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=del%20%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%29%5E%28-1%2F2%29) of $f$

[Divergence](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=div%20%7B-x%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%29%5E%283%2F2%29%2C%20-y%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%29%5E%283%2F2%29%2C%20-z%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%29%5E%283%2F2%29%7D) of $\bigtriangledown f$

Comment: I have gotten this far. Could you expand on your answer?

Comment: Details are added

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain how you got $\frac{∂^2f}{∂x^2}$?

Comment: Ah! Nevermind, I got it... This was my pitfall in the problem

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In radial coordinates ($\mathbb{R}^3$, when $f(r)$),
$$ \nabla^2 f= \Delta f= \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}  \left( r^2 \frac{ \partial f}{\partial r } \right )  \quad \text{when } r \neq 0 $$

Comment: This is the way to go, but proceed with caution, the result vanishes unless $r=0$ it is proportional to a delta function

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac1r=-\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=-\frac1{r^2}\frac{2x}{2r}=-\frac{x}{r^3},$$

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\frac1r=-\frac1{r^3}+x\frac3{r^4}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=-\frac1{r^3}+3\frac x{r^4}\frac{2x}{2r}.$$

Summing on $x,y,z$, we get

$$\nabla^2\frac1r=-\frac3{r^3}+\frac{3r^2}{r^5}=0.$$

Comment: All fixed now...